# Raising a logarithm base to a power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I was playing around with logs, and I discovered the following:
$$\log_af=x\log_{a^x}f$$
Where does this come from? Thanks.

Comment: for what stands $f,a$?

Comment: $a$ is some arbitrary base and $f$ is some arbitrary function

Comment: Just apply the change of base rule, like the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x\log_{a^x}f=\frac{x\log_af}{\log_aa^x}=\frac{x\log_af}x=\log_af$$

Comment: for $a$ we have $$a>0$$ and $$a\ne 1$$ and for $$f>0$$